# npm install -g doesn't instal globally

Tags: node.js, npm

Windows Server 2008 R2 x64, npm 3.9.6. I'm trying to install a package globally:

npm install -g gulp-cli

It goes into c:\Users[Me]\AppData\Roaming\npm

What am I missing? I'm the administrator, the command line window says "Administrator: Command prompt".

EDIT: OBTW, if I move the package folder from `C:\Users\[Me]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules`, will it work?

Comment: Just adding that you're question doesn't describe what your problem is, might want to update it.

Comment: *"npm install -g doesn't install globally, it only installs into the global folder"*

Comment: What does that mean? it **is** installing to it's global folder. As long as `c:\Users[Me]\AppData\Roaming\npm` is in your `$PATH` you can run the globally installed packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install a package locally (without the `-g` flag) it will install it under `<current directory>/node_modules`. Some packages are designed to work locally.

In your case, when you install globally, it will be installed in NPM's [global prefix](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#prefix) (which is a configuration value that can be modified).

It looks like your global prefix is set to `c:\Users[Me]\AppData\Roaming\npm`, meaning global packages will be installed there. So this doesn't look like a problem.

If your problem happens to be that you can't call your newly installed package from the `cmd.exe`, then it could be that `c:\Users[Me]\AppData\Roaming\npm` is not in your PATH, [and you need to set it](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm).

---

Comment: The problem is that user A installed it and user B can't use it. I thought the global package path was under Program Files by default; apparently not.

Comment: No, globally doesn't mean system-wide. Globally means it's a package that's not supposed to be used by a project, but ran in the CLI, ergo accessed "globally"